# Comparing performance of 2 comparable tests

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, arithmetic, geometric-mean

So I have sets of data, 15 responses for test A and 15 separate responses for test B. Tests A and B have 6 perception questions and the object is to compare the performance of representing data one way or another, one test is expected to have people perform better on answering the questions than the other. Would a t-test be sufficient to show a difference in performance even with the two test being slightly different? If so would the arithmetic mean be ok as the response range may differ on each question or would the geometric mean be better?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the distribution if the response variable. A safe bet is to report median (1st quartile, 3rd quartile) and compare with Wilcoxon rank sum test for paired data.